# Prevent Web Essentials in Visual Studio from returning Foundation column validation errors

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, zurb-foundation, web-essentials

Using Visual Studio 2013 & Web Essentials 2013 for Update 2.

I'm getting many errors from the Foundation validation in the VS Error List, which is rather annoying.

> When using "columns", you must also specify the class "small-#", "medium-#" or "large-#".
>
> When using "column", you must also specify the class "row" on the parent element.

As I'm not using the Foundation grid system, I would like to know if there's a way to prevent Web Essentials from returning these Foundation validation errors?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

We were having the same problem at my company, after a bit of digging we found the settings under Tools > options > web essentials > HTML - from here you can deactivate validation for angular.js, Bootstrap and Foundation.

Comment: Excellent, thanks!
After I had closed the file and re-opened it those annoying errors had disappeared. I'm sorry that I don't have enough rep to vote up your answer.

Comment: As a follow-up, if you don't want to turn off Bootstrap or Foundation you will get these errors spuriously -- if you have applied custom classes that include the word "column". Rename your custom classes and you should be ok.